# Qgridlayout with matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to create application with live-updating matplotlib figures in it. Therefore I use PyQt4 together witch matplotlib. I'm having a problem with the size of the Figures drawn in the Qmainwidget. I want one Figure(gauge1) to be three times smaller(Horizontal) compared to the other Figure(dc). According to the docs( if I understand them very well) This should give the right sizes:

```
    self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

    layout=QtGui.QGridLayout(self.main_widget)
    layout.setSpacing(20)
    layout.expandingDirections()

    time=Datetime() 
    dc = Plotgraph()
    gauge1=Gauge()
    #===ADD_WIDGET: at start-row,start-column, #rows , #colums======
    layout.addWidget(gauge1,1,1,2,1)
    layout.addWidget(dc,3,1,5,1)
```

However the Qwidget gauge1 is always bigger than the other one.I want to use a QgridLayout because the application has to work on different sizes of a screen. 
I also add the code of the two written classes in case their is something wrong in their. I think I'm not using the Qgridlayout the right way.

The code for the class Plotgraph:

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        fig = Figure()
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111,autoscale_on=True)
        self.axes.set_ybound(lower=0,upper=None)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

class Plotgraph(MyMplCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        MyMplCanvas.__init__(self)
        self.axes.xaxis_date()
        self.xdata=[]
        self.ydata=[]
        self.formater = md.DateFormatter(' %H:%M:%S')
        self.compute_initial_figure()
        self.timeClear=0
        self.update_figure()
        timer=QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update_figure)
        timer.start(5000)
    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass
    def update_figure(self): 
        .....
```

The code for the class Gauge:

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111,autoscale_on=True)
        self.axes.axis('off')
        self.fig.tight_layout()       

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
       pass

class Gauge(MyMplCanvas):
    def __init__(self,meter,parent=None):
        MyMplCanvas.__init__(self)

        self.compute_initial_figure()            


        timer=QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update_figure)
        timer.start(5000)
        self.update_figure()
    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

    def update_figure(self):         
       ....
```